# Не отображается объект в three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Я пишу код, для добавления .obj, созданного с помощью Blender, в three.js

```
// texture
var cylinder_texture = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

    console.log( item, loaded, total );

};

// model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'js/1.obj', function ( object ) {

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material = cylinder_texture;

        }

    } );

    object.position.x = - 60;
    object.rotation.x = 20* Math.PI / 180;
    object.rotation.z = 20* Math.PI / 180;
    object.scale.x = 30;
    object.scale.y = 30;
    object.scale.z = 30;
    obj = object
    scene.add( obj );

} );
```

И он отработал без ошибок: "OBJLoader: 5.00ms"

Но проблема в том, что этот объект не отображается, хотя все остальные объекты отображаются.

Может быть дело в том, что я размер не указал, подскажите как его указать или если есть другие ошибки, то как их исправить? 
Спасибо!

Добавляю остальной код: камеру сцену и т.д.

```
var width = 500;
var height = 600;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "radial-gradient(at bottom left, #ffffff, #E4F3FA)";

canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
canvas.setAttribute('height', height);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas,alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(width,height);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101030 );
scene.add(light);   

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, width / height, 0.1, 5000);
camera.position.set(50,150,500); //x,y,z

...
//ТУТ ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ КОД ПО ДОБАВЛЕНИЮ ОБЪЕКТА 
...

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: Много чего не понятно и вызывает вопросы. Например, `child.material.map = cylinder_texture;`, где `cylinder_texture` - `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()`, в то время как `.map` должен быть THREE.Texture(). Тут, скорее всего, нужно следующее: `child.material = cylinder_texture;`

Comment: Подправил, всё так же

Comment: В таких случаях лучше показывать полный код: инициализация сцены, камеры, рендерера и т.д., и т.п.

Comment: Добавил полный код

Comment: Попробуйте поставить `renderer.render(scene, camera);` в конец коллбэк-функции загрузки, сразу после `scene.add( obj );`

Comment: супер, спасибо, сработало!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить `renderer.render(scene, camera);` в конец коллбэк-функции загрузки, сразу после `scene.add( obj );`

Пояснение: загрузка файла - операция асинхронная, поэтому вызов `renderer.render(scene, camera);` происходил раньше, чем полная загрузка файла.